# Find minimum value on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to find out the student scored the minimum mark on the collection. I am not getting expected output. Your help would be appreciated:

```
    > db.Student.find()
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5c8a3e85e8e2bcb1a75780c4"), "Name" : "Nandhi", "Mark" : 90 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5c8a3e85e8e2bcb1a75780c5"), "Name" : "Rajan", "Mark" : 80 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5c8a3e85e8e2bcb1a75780c6"), "Name" : "Raj", "Mark" : 75 }
```

**Query:**

```
    > db.Student.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"Mark",avg_marks:{$min:1}}}])
```

**Output**

```
    { "_id" : "Mark", "avg_marks" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort by `mark` and `limit` to 1

```
db.Student.find().sort({Mark:1}).limit(1)
```

Using aggregation

```
db.Student.aggregate(
[
 {
   $group:
     {
       _id: null,
       minMark: { $min: "$Mark" }
     }
 }
])
```

Comment: I want to explore aggregation! can you please help me with rewrite the query using min keyword?

Comment: Updated answer. Please take a look on it.

Comment: There is an option group with null

Comment: Thanks, Ashwanth. It helped me a lot. If I understood correctly, _id is just the fields which we want to GROUP, in our case it is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort` and `limit`

```
db.Student.find().sort({Mark:1}).limit(1)
```